# error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android

I understand this can be caused by spelling and grammatical errors and I have double checked this part of the code. My main is to have the image 'alien' in a specific position on the canvas. The error comes from this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/spaceinvaders"
    >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/alien"
android:src="@drawable/alien"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
andriod:layout_marginTop="120dip"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the exact error? post it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is caused by your last line.

**andriod**:layout_marginTop="120dip"/>

Comment: Yeah that's what the problem was thanks, any idea of how i could move the image without getting the same error?

Comment: Just to be sure, you noticed the typo right ? (the I and O that are switched). When this typo is fixed, do you still have your problem ?